# Questions are misaligned when I visit a question from a comment link

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, internet-explorer

This one's a bit weird. Any time I view a question through a direct link to one of its comments (Whether through an inbox notification, an outside link, or just clicking the time on a comment on a page I'm already on), the page loads up with the <del>title</del> whole content area (answers, vote buttons, sidebar and all) aligned weirdly. Once I reload the page through any other link (and thus get rid of the #comment bit), it looks good again.

[image: Image of a misaligned title]

System Info: Win7, IE11, no toolbars, no add-ons, no userscripts, etc.

Comment: Can you post an example comment link where this can be reproduced?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229773/question-titles-are-misaligned-when-i-visit-a-question-from-a-comment-link?noredirect=1#comment754730_229773 is the link to your comment. Or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229773/question-titles-are-misaligned-when-i-visit-a-question-from-a-comment-link?noredirect=1#comment754731_229773 which is the link to this one. Just tested both, both caused it.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce on my end (Ubuntu, Google Chrome 32.0.1700.102). Did you test it with other browsers, @Billy?

Comment: Nah. I'm on my laptop while on vacation, and it's rarely used. Hence the OS's default browser with fully stock settings; there's not much else installed on this thing.

Comment: It's because `scrollIntoView` is called on the highlighted comment. For some reason that causes IE11 to horizontally scroll the element ancestor in addition to just vertically scrolling the page.

Comment: Ah, I'm seeing this too (Win8.1 IE11).  Was just about to post this.  It only happens on MSE.

Comment: I think this has been finally fixed.

Comment: @Troyen Just followed the link to that comment, and yeah, seems to be fine. I'll flag for a [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be working correctly now. Tested it here with Win 8.1 / IE 11 barebones. Note that I did not fix it myself; just tagged it.

Comment: You are the new mod?

Comment: @nicael I am a new developer on the Core team.

Comment: Since when? Today? Simply interesting ))

Comment: @nicael since Monday.

Comment: Ok. "You can follows" - remove the last "s" (in your about me). And you work in the team, not on the team, right? Otherwise it means that you are a servant.

Answer (score 7):

It's because `#question-header` is defined to be too wide:

```
.question-page #question-header {
    width: 980px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

…where 980 + 20 + 20 equals a width of 1020 pixels inside of `#content`, which is only 980 pixels wide. This doesn't cause layout problems in the general case because `#content` has `overflow: hidden`, but when `scrollIntoView` is called on the comment (as is the case when highlighting it when you visit via one of those links) IE apparently decides that extra width should influence how it focuses on the selected content and shifts everything to the left. Without the hidden overflow you end up with a horizontal scrollbar instead.

In cases where the title of the question is particularly long, the oversized header can also result in clipping of the title text depending on where the text wraps (at least in Chrome):

[image: clipped title text]

Assuming the width can't just be dropped, assigning the padding to `.question-page #question-header h1` instead would fix things.

Comment: Is there a fix on its way or are there more pressing bugs?

Comment: You'd have to ask a dev. :P But since it's a fairly trivial fix I hope someone will address it sometime soon.