# Comment crashes way into Hot Questions

Tags: bug, comments, design

Here, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26137/16411, a comment just goes on to the right without stopping in time.

[image]

Not seen that before, but perhaps I've not seen many comments made from phones. That must take an age, having to wait for the dial to return to its starting point up to four times per letter. They'll be telling me next you can get 'phones in different colours. Youngsters today, eh?

Oh, now I see another one on that answer doing the same. Nothing to do with 'phones.

It's not this, is it?

[image]

Comment: If that code block were of ridiculous length, that might push out the right boundary... **EDIT** Reproduced below; I had to go into devtools and delete the sidebar to reach the edit button on this comment!

Comment: `ridiculous code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        wrap yet?`

Comment: Perhaps if I now type a long comment, and just keep it going, thinking of things to type which just follow on from what has been typed already but don't really mean much, just to make it long and see if it breaks. Is that enough?

Comment: Spot on @michaelb958. Just no low enough down to overwrite the Hot Network Questions, but to slide underneath the related instead. Yoy, my page has also lost the left-hand side...

Comment: The effect of yours @michaelb958 is to also loose the left-side of my page :-)

Comment: Not even refreshing fixes it. Firefox something-or-other.

Comment: IE 11 here; if this remains unresolved in a few hours, I can test with Firefox 28.

Comment: @michaelb958 Thanks for the assistance. I'm going to sleep, I expect it'll all be tidy in the morning.

Comment: FYI, the left-side-cut-off issue is due to [this outstanding bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229773/223030).

Comment: @michaelb958 OK, I guess I clicked on your red number one in my in-tray to get the going left. I can sleep easy on that one anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same issue that was [reported at meta.stats.SE](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/rendering-error-comments-with-mathjax-syntax-errors-overflow-their-boxes) a while ago.  It's triggered by any content in a comment that does not wrap to fit inside the comment box, causing the comments table itself to extend beyond the main content area.

For what it's worth, the CSS fix I added to [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) to fix that bug works on this one too.  It basically restyles the comment table to use a fixed layout.  The specific over-wide content still overflows into the sidebar, but the surrounding comments are not affected.

For example, this is what the [comments on codegolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26125/line-up-the-csv/26137#comment56876_26137) look like to me using SOUP:

[image: Screenshot]

Alas, IE users will just have to live with the current behavior for now, unless someone figures out a way to install user scripts on IE.

Comment: [Here's another report on meta.math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/formatting-bug-long-mathjax-or-code-blocks-break-entire-post-or-page).